# Method improvement on data access via ADO.NET

Tags: c#, ado.net

Which of the two code segments below would you prefer? Why? Are there any circumstances where the other would be preferable? Could you make any further improvements?

```
 i. 
        private int GetSize(string deptName)
        {
            QueryHelper dqh = new QueryHelper();
            return dqh.GetDataSet("sp_GetDeptSize",deptName).Tables[0].Rows[0]["Size"];
        }

    ii. 
        private int GetSize(string deptName)
        {
            QueryHelper dqh = new QueryHelper();
            DataSet ds = dqh.GetDataSet("sp_GetDeptSize", deptName);
            DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
    DataRow dr = dt.Rows[0];
    int size = dr["Size"];
            return size;
        }
```

Please note that QueryHelper  is custom type.

My answer to this:
I prefer to method i, which is more concise. It seems that method ii is not preferable under any circumstances.

I need advice on further improvement on method i, and idea would be very much appreciated.

Comment: better pos at: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two methods you listed are 99% identical. The notational difference is a matter of taste.
Both still need a cast to `int`.

I would prefer skipping the DataSet and use Command.ExecuteScalar()

Comment: Both methods are not good enough! Your idea seems good to me.

Answer (score 0):

Given the code, i will say Method 2 is better as you must NULL check everything before trying to access.

what if dataset it NULL?. Method 1 will error out.

What if there is no table in the dataset? Again method 1 will error out.

What if there is a table but no row? Again method 1 will error out.

Comment: So will method 2, as it does no null checking - but at least you will get a line number in debug builds.

Comment: Both methods are not good enough! Improvement is needed.

Comment: Thanks Joe. I wonder if method 1 will work the same too, if I break each method into each line.